# Каким образом прячется реальная ссылка на видео?

Tags: javascript, html

Стандартный код видео :

```html
<video>
  <source src="url_video_mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="url_video_webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(к сожалению отловить для скрина не получается этот пример)

С такой разметкой при клике `ПКМ` видео будет доступно для скачивания , каким образом прячется реальная ссылка на видео ?Какую ставить метку не знаю и предположительно это либо **php** либо **js**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

тег `<video>` это html5 элемент для внедрения видео в html-документ. Это *не* ссылка. Браузер знает, как обработать этот тег (показать видео/добавить пункт "скачать" в контекстное меню). Поскольку это *не* ссылка (*синтаксически* -  как тег - *семантически*, это, конечно же ссылка) , то прятать тут нечего, и нечего показывать в статусной строке. Хотя, при желании разработчика, конечно, браузер может это делать.

если говорить про "как прятать ссылку на скачать из меню":
если вы нажмете правой кнопкой на youtube видео, увидите, что там есть пункт "about html5 player", который, по сути, представляет собой js/html обвязку вокруг тега , перехват контекстного меню (прозрачный див поверх видео, например), выдача собственного меню и т.д. дальше нагуглить можно - например - http://videojs.com/

Comment: зайдите в youtube или в bobfilm и тот же правый клик и того пункта в меню не будет уже , я же не говорил о теге видео я говорил о ссылке на видео  которую как то скрывают

Comment: недопонял вопрос, проверил, отредактировал ответ, и тег js вернул на место :-)

Comment: за правый клик спасибо Это решение вопроса